# Problema ao tratar objeto json na requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

tenho uma função que faz um cadastro no banco de dados via ajax e logo depois busca esse mesmo objeto no banco para adicionar as informações referentes a ele sem recarregar a página.

```
var respostaSubmit = function (response) {
    alertGeneric('modal-info', 'Aviso', response.Mensagem, response.Action); // aqui é feito o cadastro do objeto, funciona normalmente

    //ESTALINHA ABAIXO NEM MESMO É CARREGADAS 

    adicionarNovaAtividadeNaLista(); //função que busca o objeto no banco e adiciona ele na tela
};

function adicionarNovaAtividadeNaLista() {
    //abaixo é chamado um método no c# que busca o objeto no bacno e o retorna em formato json

    executeAjax(URLS.BuscarUltimaAtividade.format('atividade', idAtividade), 'GET', 'html', function (response) {
        //Abaixo o objeto retornado seria tratado para ser adicionado na tela

        var lista = document.getElementById('atividades');
        lista.outerHTML = lista.outerHTML.replace('</ul>', '<li class="atividade-style list-group-item" name="' + response[0].id + '"><span class="atividade">' + response[0].nome + '</span><div class="pull-right btn-group" style="position: absolute; right: 8px;"><button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o excluir-atividae btnSemBorda" onClick="editaAtividade(' + response[0].id + ')"></button></div></li></ul>');
    });
}
```

Comment: não sei se isso te ajuda, mas você não precisa cadastrar e buscar para ter os dados, você pode retornar o objeto cadastrado na sua chamada AJAX de cadastro.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas na verdade preciso. Tenho que adicionar na tela tambem o id do banco que só existe depois do cadastro ser feito.

Comment: agora vi aqui nos comentários do seu código que esta usando C#, também uso, e apos a inclusão no banco consigo retornar o objeto cadastrado, ou seja já com ID.